# Handling KML/CSV with geopandas - DriverError: unsupported driver: u'CSV'

Tags: python, kml, csv, geopandas

I'm trying to import a dataset of UK postcode districts [UK postcode districts](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/data?docid=1jgWYtlqGSPzlIa-is8wl1cZkVIWEm_89rWUwqFU#rows:id=1) from Google Fusion tables into geopandas with the aim of splicing it to a dataset of house prices.

The problem is that geopandas doesn't seem to like either the CSV/KML version of the data.

If I use the command geopandas.from_file(path) then I receive the error:

```
DriverError: unsupported driver: u'CSV'
```

I have the same error when I try to import a KML version of the data (You can download the data below).

I'm sure it's trivial, but can anyone work out what I'm doing wrong?

[UK postcode districts - KML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v1hdsqwhlt507wf/UK_postcode_districts.kml?dl=0)

[UK postcode districts - CSV](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yl1lums4qv3lcou/UK_postcode_districts.csv?dl=0)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in case of csv, it probably would be easier to read it with pandas and then convert it to geopandas Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gp
from shapely.geometry import Point

stations = pd.read_csv('../data/stations.csv')
stations['geometry'] = stations.apply(lambda z: Point(z.X, z.Y), axis=1)
stations = gp.GeoDataFrame(stations)
```

Answer (score 19):

The KML driver isn't enabled by default as detailed in this github issue https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/97. Basically, the KML driver doesn't seem to meet Fiona's quality requirements (as of 2014), not sure if it will be fixed in the future.

You could **try** to read a simple/standard-enough KML as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['kml'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default

gpd.read_file("/path/to/your/test.kml")
```

I've tried to read a file [here](ftp://sidads.colorado.edu/pub/DATASETS/AGDC/nsidc0523_smith_V01/NSIDC_Lakes/Antarctic_lakes.kml) and it gave me the following output:

[image]

Credits to this gist:

https://gist.github.com/timtroendle/6f61dc38a0aad58c2261524d7d8594c3

Edit 20191021: With newer versions of `fiona`, you might need to use `libkml` instead of `kml`. I.e.:

```
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['libkml'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['LIBKML'] = 'rw' # enable KML support which is disabled by default
```

Answer (score 7):

GeoPandas relies on the Fiona library (http://github.com/toblerity/Fiona) for the `from_file()` implementation. At this time Fiona, and therefore GeoPandas, does not support CSV or KML input. If you can convert them to GeoJSON or Shapefiles, then GeoPandas should be able to read without a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The current version of GeoPandas (0.10.2) can be made to read KML via the following code_snippet:

```
import geopandas as gp
gp.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'

df = gp.read_file('sample_file.kml', driver='KML')
```

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Fiona supports the CSV driver out of the box. You may have to specify the names of the latitude and longitude columns like this:

```
geopandas.read_file("file.csv", X_POSSIBLE_NAMES="X", Y_POSSIBLE_NAMES="Y")
```

More information about possible arguments for the csv driver can be found in the gdal driver documentation: https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/csv.html#open-options