# How to convert CSV to point shapefile using Python?

Tags: python, shapefile, convert, csv

```
import csv,sys
import osgeo.ogr, osgeo.osr #we will need some packages
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import *
import osgeo.osr as osr


def test():
    boolValue = True
    canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
    spatialReference = osr.SpatialReference() #will create a spatial reference locally to tell the system what the reference will be
    spatialReference.ImportFromEPSG(4326) #here we define this reference to be the EPSG code
    driver = osgeo.ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile') # will select the driver for our shp-file creation.
    export_shp = r'E:\Folder'
    shapeData = driver.CreateDataSource(export_shp) #so there we will store our data
    outLayer = shapeData.CreateLayer(str('WaypointLayer'), spatialReference, osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint) #this will create a corresponding layer for our data with given spatial information.
    outDataSource = driver.Open(export_shp, 1)
    outLayer = outDataSource.GetLayer()
    layer_defn = outLayer.GetLayerDefn() # gets parameters of the current shapefile
    index = 0

# Reading the CSV file
    cnt = 0
    input_file = r'E:\Folder\CSV\points.csv' 
    with open(input_file, 'rb') as csvfile:
        readerDict = csv.DictReader(csvfile)


# Create the fields in the layer
        for header in readerDict.fieldnames:
            field_name = ogr.FieldDefn(header, ogr.OFTString)
            field_name.SetWidth(50)
            outLayer.CreateField(field_name)


        for row in readerDict:
            print (row['latitude'], row['longitude'])
            point = osgeo.ogr.Geometry(osgeo.ogr.wkbPoint)
            point.AddPoint(float(row['longitude']), float(row['latitude'])) #we do have LATs and LONs as Strings, so we convert them
            feature = osgeo.ogr.Feature(layer_defn)
            feature.SetGeometry(point) #set the coordinates
            feature.SetFID(index)

            for field in readerDict.fieldnames:
                i = feature.GetFieldIndex(field)
                feature.SetField(i, row[field])
            outLayer.CreateFeature(feature)
            index += 1
    shapeData.Destroy()
    outDataSource.Destroy()
    conLayer = QgsVectorLayer(export_shp,'pointLayer',"ogr")
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(conLayer)
    canvas.refresh()
```

The problem is that initially it is not updating the data in the attribute table but it creates the features when I executed once. When I executed again it is updating the field data.  It sometimes create duplicates also.

What I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

The question is "PyQGIS: How to convert the CSV to point shape file using python" and you only use ogr, Python only without PyQGIS.

In fact, you don't need PyQGIS or ArcPy, you can use Python only and  there are alternatives to ogr, easier ([Problem intersecting shapefiles with OGR in Python](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/176582/2581))

- the best solution is [GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas), you read the csv file as a [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) Dataframe, you convert it in a GeoDataFrame and you save the GeoDataframe as a shapefile (look at [csv: Convert a pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-geodataframe) or [Handling KML/CSV with geopandas - DriverError: unsupported driver: u'CSV'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164886/2581)
- you can also use [PyShp (shapefile)](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) as in [Using PyShp to convert polygons in *.csv to *.shp files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/70825/2581) with  [PyShp (shapefile)](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) or [csv to shp missing file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/115398/2581)
- and  [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html)[Using Fiona to write a new shapefile from scratch](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/97563/2581) with [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html)
- you can also use [GeoPandas](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas) to directly open the csv file and convert it to a shapefile ([csv: Convert a pandas DataFrame to a GeoDataFrame](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/174159/convert-a-pandas-dataframe-to-a-geodataframe), [Handling KML/CSV with geopandas - DriverError: unsupported driver: u'CSV'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/164886/2581)

Comment: I am doing in QGIS and my code is working fine except that the layer is not editable first time but it is editable second time even though i am doing destroy() at the end. So if i want the layer to be editable what changes i have to do ?

Answer (score 2):

What GIS software are you using? ArcGIS or QGIS.

If ArcGIS this should be fairly simple:

```
arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(InputCSV, "lng", "lat", "xylayer")
```

and then

```
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(xylayer, outputDir, fcName)
```

*Also would you want any other information besides the xy locations from the csv file?

I do not know how to do this in QGIS

Comment: This only works on a system with Esri's Arcgis installed. Those that do large automated processes might not want to use Windows on their servers, meaning no Esri installation and no arcpy lib.